# Installing pandasql or sqltopandas into Spyder 4.0

Tags: python, sql, pandas, spyder, pandasql

I am trying to use SQL commands on panda data frames, but am having trouble installing any sort of package from the command line, Spyder 4.0 or Jupyter notes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install any other libraries if you already have `pandas` installed. There is a function called `pandas.read_sql_query()` which enables to read the sql queries. You can find more info on this [link.](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-pandas-databases/)